# Inner product spaces from vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

Let $S = \{(x, y) \mid x, y \in R \}$ and define vector addition and scalar multiplication in the same way as $R^2$. Define an inner product in $S$ according to the formula $\left<u, v\right> = 2v_1 u_1 - v_1 u_2 - v_2 u_1 + v_2 u_2$ and show that $S$ equipped with this inner product is a real inner product space.

Now, I know that for $R^2$ we can let $u = (u_1, u_2)$ and $v = (v_1, v_2)$ be vectors in $S$ and that for addition $ (u + v) = (v + u)$ and multiplication $k(u, v) = (ku + kv)$.

Then for inner product spaces I know the 4 axioms have to hold:

$\left<u, v\right> = \left<v, u\right>$

$\left<u + v, w\right> = \left<u, w\right> + \left<v, w\right>$

$\left<ku, v\right> = k\left<u, v\right>$

$\left<v,v\right> > 0$, and $\left<v,v\right> = 0$ iff $v = 0$

But I'm not quite sure what the question is asking for and how to use these findings to answer it. Is it just asking to show the 4 axioms hold according to the defined formula?

Comment: Yes, you are asked to  verify that the axioms for an inner product are satisfied.

Comment: I have edited some of your TeX, but please edit the rest yourself. It makes everything very difficult to read.

Comment: So how do the vectors for $R^2$ come into it?

Comment: And it isn't supposed to look like that Amor

Comment: What **was** it supposed to look like?    "Vectors in $R^2$ come into it in the way the inner product was defined:  $<u, v>= u_1v_1- u_1v_2- u_2v_2+ u_2v_2$ requires that $u= (u_1, u_2)$ and $v= (v_1, v_2)$ in $R^2$.